# Accuracy Problems with Spatial Anchors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to implement an Azure Spatial Anchors Application for iOS with Unity. Sadly the accuracy of relocating the anchor leaves alot to be desired and is really inconsistent. When i place and anchor and try to relocate it from the exact same position where i placed it from, it either doesn't find the anchor at all or places it up to a few meters away from the position I orginally placed it. It's not really consistent either, trying to locate the same anchor from the same position on the same device gives me a different outcome everytime (or it just doesn't find it).

I've tried to fix this issue for some days now and I don't know what to do anymore. I've tried to replace my own code with the code from the sample project, different locations, different lighting conditions.. nothing really gave me a consistent experience. There doesn't seem to be alot of documentation or a huge community behind it, so I couldn't find anyone else with that problem. So right now I'm not sure what's the problem: my code or just Spatial Anchors still being worked on. At least in the keynote they talked about this service being very accurate and showed examples of it working really well.

Like I said, the code I used is really close to the sample project.

First the user scans the environment until its 'RecommendedForCreateProgress' is at 100%. Then he can place the object, change its scale and save it to the SpatialAnchors service.

```
//...
//Placing/ Moving the anchor
if (localAnchor == null)
        {
            localAnchor = Instantiate(testPrefab, hitPosition, rotation);
            localAnchor.AddARAnchor();
        }
        else
        {
            localAnchor.RemoveARAnchor();
            localAnchor.transform.position = hitPosition;
            localAnchor.transform.rotation = rotation;
            localAnchor.AddARAnchor();
        }
//...

//...
//Saving the anchor and its properties
    Vector3 localScale = localAnchor.transform.localScale;
   CloudSpatialAnchor cloudAnchor = new CloudSpatialAnchor();
        cloudAnchor.AppProperties[@"scaleX"] = localScale.x.ToString();
        cloudAnchor.AppProperties[@"scaleY"] = localScale.y.ToString();
        cloudAnchor.LocalAnchor = localAnchor.GetNativeAnchorPointer();
        await this.cloudSession.CreateAnchorAsync(cloudAnchor);
```

After that the ID gets saved in a database.
I check with the GPS position if the user is nearby a CloudAnchor, then create a watcher. When the watcher finds the anchor I get the position and rotation and instantiate my object there.

```
private void AnchorLocated(AnchorLocatedEventArgs args){  
//...
Pose anchorPose = args.Anchor.GetAnchorPose();
CreateGameObject(anchorPose.position, anchorPose.rotation, args.Anchor);
//...
}

private void CreateGameObject(){
GameObject anchorObject = Instantiate(anchorPrefab, position, rotation);
anchorObject.AddARAnchor();

//scaling object
}
```

Scaling the object doesn't make a difference, even if i don't use it it's still inaccurate.
I've been trying to get the inaccuracy is only in the range of centimeters and not meters.
Getting the pointcloud to 200% doesn't make much of a difference either.

Comment: Update: Checked out the Spatial Anchors Local Shared Demo and it works pretty well. Code doesn't seem to different though. Maybe I'm doing something wrong while relocating the anchor?

Comment: Hi Chris, were you able to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi Alberto, sadly I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: Does the anchorPrefab have a transform associated with it in the Unity Editor?

Comment: Yes it does have a transform component

Comment: Is the transform on the prefab at position 0,0,0 and rotation 0,0,0?

Comment: Yes the position and rotation are both set to 0,0,0.

Comment: Can you please file a support request @ https://aka.ms/azsupt? If you do not have access to a support plan, please reach out @ AZCommunity@microsoft.com with a link to this thread as well as your subscription ID and we can help get the support ticket opened for this issue.